# Decrypted image starts good but becomes gray

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

I am working on a personal project of mine and was wondering how I can fix my issue.

Here is a piece of code I am working on:

```
f = open('sample.jpeg','rb')
choice = int(input("-> "))

mutableBytes = bytearray(f.read())
f.close()
print(str(mutableBytes) + "SAMPLE")
if choice == 1:
    for i in range(len(mutableBytes)):
        if mutableBytes[i] < 255:
          mutableBytes[i] = mutableBytes[i] + 1
          f.close()
    print(str(mutableBytes) + "ENCRYPTED")
    f = open('samplecopy.jpeg','wb+')
    f.write(mutableBytes)
else:
    f = open('samplecopy.jpeg','rb')
    mutableBytes = bytearray(f.read())
    f.close()
    for i in range(len(mutableBytes)):
        if mutableBytes[i] > 0 and mutableBytes[i]<255:
            mutableBytes[i] = mutableBytes[i] - 1
    f = open('samplecopy.jpeg','wb+')
    f.write(mutableBytes)
    print(str(mutableBytes) + "Decrypted")
```

This should in theory get a picture and encrypt it, after decrypt it. I printed all the bytes and I looked for changes but it looks the same.

Here is the comparison: https://www.diffchecker.com/vTtzGe4O

And here is the image I get vs the original:

[image: Original image vs corrupted]

(the bottom one is the one I get after decrypting).

Comment: The diffchecker link indicates there are differences; have you looked into those? (The diff isn't very good, perhaps you can find a better one which focuses on the actual changes better. Notice also how it replaced some binary stuff -- probably a sequence containing an @ sign -- with the text "[email protected]"!)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip. I managed to make it work in C and will try to port it to Python. I will update you.

Comment: Values 254 and 255 encrypts to the same value (255) which makes correct decryption impossible.

Comment: Yes, i see that issue now. Thank you all. Its just my logic was not on point.

Comment: if you do the math mod 256 it should work, i.e. on encrypt do `mutableBytes[i] = (mutableBytes[i] + 1) % 256`, and in decrypt do `mutableBytes[i] = (mutableBytes[i] - 1) % 256`. Remove the if statements altogether.

Comment: That worked. Thank you!